# Function to evaluate loan eligibility

Tags: typescript

I have a function and am wondering whether I have written it the most performant way by using multiple guard clauses in the code above some of the variable declaraciont.

Here is my code:

```
// option 1 - most efficient?
const checker = (
  hasBingoLoan = false,
  options,
  udlViewGrid,
  notifications
): EligibilityResult => {
  const notificationCode: string | undefined = notifications?.[0]?.code;
  const isInArrears: boolean = arrearsChecker(notificationCode);
  const hasMaxLoans: boolean = maxLoanChecker(notificationCode);

  if (isInArrears || hasMaxLoans)
    return { eligibilityType: notificationCode, isInArrears, hasMaxLoans };
  // don't need to continue if isInArrears || hasMaxLoans

  const lmsDown: boolean = notificationCode === LMS_DOWN;
  const noOptions: boolean = !!options.length; // don't need !!, but clear

  if (lmsDown && noOptions) {
    return {eligibilityType: LMS_DOWN_NO_OPTIONS, isInArrears, hasMaxLoans}
  }
  // don't need to continue if lmsDown && noOptions

  const firstOptionEligible: boolean = options[0]?.eligible === 'YES';
  const secondOptionEligible: boolean = options?.[1]?.eligible === 'YES'; // need ?. as options arr may only have 1 item
  let eligibilityType: string = NOT_ELIGIBLE;

  // could make switch statement
  if (lmsDown && firstOptionEligible) {
    eligibilityType = LMS_DOWN_SIMO
  } else if (hasBingoLoan) {
    eligibilityType = BLOCKED;
    udlViewGrid.renewUpgradeOverlayBlocked();
  } else if (!hasBingoLoan && firstOptionEligible && secondOptionEligible) {
    eligibilityType = UPGRADE;
    udlViewGrid.renewUpgradeOverlayEligible();
  } else {
    udlViewGrid.renewUpgradeOverlayNotEligible();
  }

  return { eligibilityType, isInArrears, hasMaxLoans };
};
```

I think it is the more efficient way, but something feels wierd about all of the variable declarations below and above the other guard clauses.

Otherwise, here is option 2:

```
// option 2?
const checker = (
  hasBingoLoan = false,
  options,
  udlViewGrid,
  notifications
): EligibilityResult => {
  const notificationCode: string | undefined = notifications?.[0]?.code;
  const isInArrears: boolean = arrearsChecker(notificationCode);
  const hasMaxLoans: boolean = maxLoanChecker(notificationCode);
  const lmsDown: boolean = notificationCode === LMS_DOWN;
  const noOptions: boolean = !!options.length;
  const firstOptionEligible: boolean = options?.[0]?.eligible === 'YES'; // need to check ?. as options may be empty
  const secondOptionEligible: boolean = options?.[1]?.eligible === 'YES';
  let eligibilityType: string = NOT_ELIGIBLE;
  // need to create all of the above variables unnecessarily?

  //could also use a switch
  if (isInArrears || hasMaxLoans) {
    eligibilityType = notificationCode
  } else if (lmsDown && noOptions) {
    eligibilityType = LMS_DOWN_NO_OPTIONS
  } else if (lmsDown && firstOptionEligible) {
    eligibilityType = LMS_DOWN_SIMO
  } else if (hasBingoLoan) {
    eligibilityType = BLOCKED;
    udlViewGrid.renewUpgradeOverlayBlocked();
  } else if (!hasBingoLoan && firstOptionEligible && secondOptionEligible) {
    eligibilityType = UPGRADE;
    udlViewGrid.renewUpgradeOverlayEligible();
  } else {
    udlViewGrid.renewUpgradeOverlayNotEligible();
  }

  return { eligibilityType, isInArrears, hasMaxLoans };
};
```

Which option is best? I am assuming option 1 since it returns early and only runs the code that it needs to. I know that you can't see all of my code, but just imagine that functions like `arrearsChecker` and `maxLoanChecker` just run a function and use some power/bandwidth, which I assume I should minimise - and the options supplied by the back-end can change (but is still an array) and may have 0, 1 or more items within it, hence the `?.` checks.

I'm curious to hear anyone's thoughts? Thank you

Comment: This code is not syntactically valid JavaScript. I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3.

Answer (score 1):

As this code has so much if/else, one of the biggest risks is having it be misread by a future developer.

With that goal in mind, I think the first version minimizes the problem better. By declaring variables right where they are used, and exiting when you've done the right checks, it puts less mental burden on a reader.

But there are a few other thoughts:

- it seems to have some side effects: doing something in the `renewUpgradeOverlayBlocked()` and similar methods. At first blush this appeared to be a function that calculated a return value; having it also modify things will be harder to maintain. I'd look to see see if I could separate out the "check" from the "act" code.
- to my eye, there are too many inputs and outputs. I don't understand the business logic here, so I can't really help, but I'd work on pulling it apart a little bit, or introducing a new abstraction. If it simply returns `eligibilityType` is that useful? Maybe the caller could be responsible for working with `udlViewGrid`?
- you can remove the comments that explain what a `return` statement does

Comment: thanks for your comments. This is in fact code that I have built upon and re-written that was initially built by a colleague. Initially it didn't have, for example, the `firstOptionEligible` variable that I added, just repeats of `options?.[0]?.eligible === 'YES';` in multiple places which I thought was messy and unclear, and no types. By saying to separate "check" from the "act" code, could you be more specific? I assume option 1 is also more performant

Comment: I mean try to separate the concerns. You're doing two things here:  (1) determining an eligibility type (2) updating some view. If you can write two separate functions for those-- and maybe an enclosing function that coordinates the two-- it should end up being simpler.  I honestly wouldn't worry about performance unless you're having a specific issue-- and at that point the solution will  likely involve caching more than if/then optimization.